# GADOCategories_GADOAdLoader_Mediation crash

Tags: admob, nskeyedarchiver

We got this weird crash recently, but can't figure out why it happens. When browsing through the crash log, it seems that networking activity and Admob are involved.

Now, this crash incident hits 2000. And it seemed to slow down from 2018/11/03.

The crashed thread is pasted down below with some other threads' backtrace deleted.

````
```
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd2e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379e288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18356bd0c abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363edf4 _szone_default_reader.34 + 422
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363f7d8 free_list_checksum_botch + 36
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363f7a0 small_free_list_remove_ptr_no_clear + 712
6  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1836362d0 small_malloc_from_free_list + 508
7  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x183633e60 szone_malloc_should_clear + 2064
8  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1836335dc malloc_zone_malloc + 160
9  CoreFoundation                 0x183ba6a78 __CFBasicHashRehash + 404
10 Foundation                     0x1844d0a18 -[NSKeyedArchiver replaceObject:withObject:] + 312
11 Foundation                     0x18452a054 _encodeObject + 320
12 Foundation                     0x1844e3ad4 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 168
13 Camera360                      0x101ffbcf8 GADOCategories_GADOAdLoader_Mediation + 2065640
14 Camera360                      0x101ffb8a4 GADOCategories_GADOAdLoader_Mediation + 2064532
15 Camera360                      0x1020376d4 GADOURLProtocolRegister + 2309828
16 CFNetwork                      0x18410854c -[__NSURLSessionLocal _protocolClassForTask:] + 436
17 CFNetwork                      0x1841087ac -[__NSURLSessionLocal _createCanonicalRequestForTask:] + 88
18 CFNetwork                      0x1842668b4 URLConnectionClient::_internalEvent_WillSendRequest() + 108
19 CFNetwork                      0x184265634 URLConnectionClient::_connectionClientInterface_startConnection(__CFRunLoop*, __CFString const*) + 224
20 CFNetwork                      0x18419f868 invocation function for block in ClassicURLConnection::start() + 52
21 CFNetwork                      0x1841a0830 invocation function for block in ClassicURLConnection::withClientAsync(void (ConnectionClientInterface*) block_pointer) + 28
22 CFNetwork                      0x1842651c0 invocation function for block in URLConnectionInstanceData::withWorkQueueAsync(void () block_pointer) const + 28
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x183468aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x183468a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1834729b4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1834732fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x183473cc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x18347c098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb08 start_wqthread + 4

--

#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  Camera360                      0x10199c488 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(void*), void*> >(void*) + 3844916
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18356c8f0 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 384
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18351625c exit + 24
3  UIKit                          0x18da64f00 -[UIApplication applicationWillTerminate] + 466
4  UIKit                          0x18dd838c4 __98-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:]_block_invoke.271 + 336
5  UIKit                          0x18db6d884 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 296
6  UIKit                          0x18db63958 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 384
7  UIKit                          0x18da4851c _afterCACommitHandler + 132
8  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1e910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
9  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
10 CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
11 CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
12 GraphicsServices               0x185a22020 GSEventRunModal + 100
13 UIKit                          0x18da5c758 UIApplicationMain + 236
14 Camera360                      0x100ca8d88 main (main.mm:122)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x1834cdfc0 start + 4




#19. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#20. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#21. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#22. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#23. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#24. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#25. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#26. BackgroundWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102db0608 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (ThreadUtility.h:25)
4  Camera360                      0x102a4ff1c JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*) (AtomicOps.h:39)
5  Camera360                      0x102a4f558 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:852)
6  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#27. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  Camera360                      0x1031b2dbc algThreadJobQueueThreadFunc + 1173380
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#28. UnitySubstanceThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102a0faa8 SubstanceSystem::ThreadMain(void*) (SubstanceSystem.cpp:549)
4  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#29. AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbc60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1ee40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  AVFAudio                       0x189538398 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6  AVFAudio                       0x1895627a8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#30. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  Camera360                      0x10317cf4c FMOD_OS_Semaphore_Wait(FMOD_OS_SEMAPHORE*) + 952596
2  Camera360                      0x1031989d0 FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 1065880
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#31. AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbc60 mach_msg + 72
2  AudioToolbox                   0x187775d38 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 260
3  AudioToolbox                   0x18777a5bc AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 156
4  AudioToolbox                   0x187add79c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#32. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd604 __semwait_signal + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18351612c nanosleep + 212
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18351604c usleep + 64
3  Camera360                      0x10317cac0 FMOD_OS_Time_Sleep(unsigned int) + 951432
4  Camera360                      0x1031989bc FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 1065860
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#33. UnityPreload
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x102b67908 PreloadManager::Run() (PreloadManager.cpp:338)
4  Camera360                      0x102b67890 PreloadManager::Run(void*) (PreloadManager.cpp:206)
5  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#34. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd0e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379fc90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2  Camera360                      0x10311d138 Geo::Impl::WaitForMultipleObjects(unsigned int, Geo::Impl::t_HANDLE**, bool, int) (GeoEvent.cpp:154)
3  Camera360                      0x10311d334 Geo::GeoEvent::Wait(unsigned int) (GeoEvent.cpp:245)
4  Camera360                      0x103104534 Enlighten::MultithreadCpuWorkerCommon::CommandThreadFunction(void*) (MultithreadCpuWorker.cpp:1252)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#35. EnlightenWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbe24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346af48 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18346b8e0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3  Camera360                      0x1029401f0 TUpdateFunction(void*) (HLRTThreadGroup.cpp:140)
4  Camera360                      0x102c0fc24 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:35)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#36. com.vstudio.makeImageSDKThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd604 __semwait_signal + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18351612c nanosleep + 212
2  Foundation                     0x1845c1214 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 136
3  Camera360                      0x101b3827c -[pg_sdk_api_image_background_manager pRunLoopBackgroundThread] (pg_sdk_api_image_background_manager.m:280)
4  Foundation                     0x1845c1efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#37. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd130 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1837a0604 _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1837a0550 _pthread_mutex_lock_slow$VARIANT$mp + 260
3  Camera360                      0x1016196ec +[PGFBHelp lockGlobal] (PGFBHelp.m:73)
4  Camera360                      0x101629270 -[PGLogCollecter writeFeedbackInfoToFile:] (PGLogCollecter.m:133)
5  Camera360                      0x10162a910 -[PGRunLoopContext invoke] (PGRunLoopContext.m:89)
6  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1f404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
7  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1ec2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
8  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c79c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
9  CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10 CoreFoundation                 0x183a8cb28 CFRunLoopRun + 116
11 Camera360                      0x1016293c0 -[PGLogCollecter handleCollectThreadFun:] (PGLogCollecter.m:167)
12 Foundation                     0x1845c1efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#38. AFNetworking
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbc60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1ee40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x1844b1674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1845261a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  Camera360                      0x10136ddf8 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:164)
8  Foundation                     0x1845c1efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#39. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb04 start_wqthread + 122

#40. Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835fd2e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379e288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18356bd0c abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363edf4 _szone_default_reader.34 + 422
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363f7d8 free_list_checksum_botch + 36
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18363f7a0 small_free_list_remove_ptr_no_clear + 712
6  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1836362d0 small_malloc_from_free_list + 508
7  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x183633e60 szone_malloc_should_clear + 2064
8  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1836335dc malloc_zone_malloc + 160
9  CoreFoundation                 0x183ba6a78 __CFBasicHashRehash + 404
10 Foundation                     0x1844d0a18 -[NSKeyedArchiver replaceObject:withObject:] + 312
11 Foundation                     0x18452a054 _encodeObject + 320
12 Foundation                     0x1844e3ad4 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 168
13 Camera360                      0x101ffbcf8 GADOCategories_GADOAdLoader_Mediation + 2065640
14 Camera360                      0x101ffb8a4 GADOCategories_GADOAdLoader_Mediation + 2064532
15 Camera360                      0x1020376d4 GADOURLProtocolRegister + 2309828
16 CFNetwork                      0x18410854c -[__NSURLSessionLocal _protocolClassForTask:] + 436
17 CFNetwork                      0x1841087ac -[__NSURLSessionLocal _createCanonicalRequestForTask:] + 88
18 CFNetwork                      0x1842668b4 URLConnectionClient::_internalEvent_WillSendRequest() + 108
19 CFNetwork                      0x184265634 URLConnectionClient::_connectionClientInterface_startConnection(__CFRunLoop*, __CFString const*) + 224
20 CFNetwork                      0x18419f868 invocation function for block in ClassicURLConnection::start() + 52
21 CFNetwork                      0x1841a0830 invocation function for block in ClassicURLConnection::withClientAsync(void (ConnectionClientInterface*) block_pointer) + 28
22 CFNetwork                      0x1842651c0 invocation function for block in URLConnectionInstanceData::withWorkQueueAsync(void () block_pointer) const + 28
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x183468aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x183468a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1834729b4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1834732fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x183473cc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x18347c098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb08 start_wqthread + 4

#41. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbc60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1ee40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x18434a6e0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x1845c1efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#42. MVAFNetworking
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1835dbc60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1ee40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x183b1c908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183a3cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x1844b1674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1845261a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  Camera360                      0x102163784 +[MVAFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 3538804
8  Foundation                     0x1845c1efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379d110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb10 thread_start + 4

#43. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18379bb04 start_wqthread + 122


```
````

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: No. The crash is very serious considering only hundreds of them occurred recently. So, we have to ignore it at present.